# Can't import the named export 'PublicKey' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: web3js, solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, candy-machine

Describe the bug
Hi, I'm trying using Metaplex to upload the assets and verify the collection, I am now moving towards "Minting Website": https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/mint-frontend

run rpm start inside the folder ~/metaplex/js/packages/candy-machine-ui to test the mint button, it doesn't load the localhost and it shows me the following error on the terminal:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@solana/buffer-layout-utils/lib/esm/web3.mjs
Can't import the named export 'PublicKey' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

Anyone know how to solve this? thanks

I'm using Visual Studio on Windows, node 14.15.

Update:
It seems I'm not alone:
https://github.com/solana-labs/buffer-layout-utils/issues/6

**Solved it:**
How to downgrade the version of Solana to 1.9.1

Comment: Downgrading didn't solve this for me. Instead, the instructions in this comment for CRA v4 did the trick: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/265/#issuecomment-1025285873

Answer (score 0):

For some reason **yarn install** wasn't doing it for me like in the docs.

I deleted *node_module*, *package-lock.json* and *yarn.lock* then installed with npm instead

```
npm install && npm start
```

that worked for me